# Python function is changing the value of my input, and I can't figure out why

Tags: python, function, input

This is my first question, so if I'm being a total dweeb posting this, let me know why and how I can avoid it in the future!

I have a bit of python code that should just take a list, and multiply the jth component by -1. This is the code in question.

```
def flip(spins,j):
    z = spins
    z[j] = z[j]*-1
    return z
```

However, what I am noticing is that if I try to do something like

```
spin = [1,1,1]
test = flip(spin,1)
```

it will assign the proper value [1,-1,1] to 'test', but it will also change the value of 'spin' to [1,-1,1]. I know there must be something totally obvious I'm overlooking, but I've been staring at this for 2 hours and still can't see it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Lists are mutable.  You're passing a reference to that list to `flip`, making a second reference to that list, then mutating the list.

Comment: CHeck this: http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-python

Comment: Since this is your first question, you might not be aware of SO etiquette - you should acknowledge the most helpful answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Comment: The same thing happens with pandas data frame as well, is it the only way to avoid this. by using df.copy and then using new object to pass through a function?

Comment: @JAbr I believe that's correct. If you don't want to mess with your original data frame, copy it and operate on the copy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inside your function, `z` and `spins` refer to the same list, which is also known by the global name of `spin`. If you modify one, those changes are visible through the other names as well. The variable `z` is superfluous.

If you want `z` to be a *copy* of `spins` then just do:

```
z = spins[:]
```

or:

```
z = list(spins)
```

Comment: So when a function receives an input, it does not put it in a black box of its own. It will actually change the input if that input is edited and used inside the function?

Comment: right. a function argument refers to same object that was passed in. if you don't change what object the argument refers to (using `=` specifically) then it's still the same object as was passed in, and any changes you make can be seen by the caller

Comment: Hmm, does not work for me. Whatever method I use, the function still alters the original object.

Comment: or for dictionaries you can use `dict(your_dictionary)`

Answer (score 3):

In Python, all objects are referenced by pointers. All variable names like `spin` and `test` are just pointers. When you assign `spin` to `z` you are just making `z` point to the same object as `spin` and then mutating the object pointed to by `z` (which is the same as the object pointed to by `spin`).

All function calls in Python are pass-by-value where the values are direct references to objects. Thus, if you mutate a list object within a function, it will appear mutated even after you return from the function.

You have to create a new copy of the list if you don't want to accidentally mutate `spin`. Other answers have shown ways of copying a list. I personally like the `[:]` syntax that kindall showed in his answer.

Comment: I just tried this code

    a=4
    b = a
    a = 5
    print b

and it would seem I should get 5, but it actually printed 4. What's the difference here?

Comment: @aetb The difference is that integers in Python are not mutable. Therefore when you do 'a=5' you are not changing the value of the object pointed to by a. You are actually creating a new integer value '5' and making 'a' point to that.

Comment: @aetb Lists, on the other hand, are mutable objects. So when you do something like z[j] = z[j]*-1 you are actually just mutating (changing the state of) the list object.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you are forgetting is that `z` and `spins` are essentially the same object. Both point to the same list and have the same elements.

For example:

```
a = [0]
b = a

b[0] = 1
print a
```

Result:

```
[1]
```

To copy the list instead, try something like this:

```
a = [0]
b = a[:]

b[0] = 1
print a
```

Result:

```
[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea that's how it worked. I thought variables all pointed to unique locations.

Answer (score 0):

```
z = spins
```

puts two names on the same object. This also happens with `num = old_num` but since you can never change numbers in-place (they're immutable) something like `number = number * -1` just gives `number * -1` the label `number` and removes the old one.

When you do

```
z[j] = ...
```

you're changing z, not assigning, which is why this changes *both* of the labelled items. What you want to do is make a copy, which you can do like:

```
z = spins[:]     # Traditional way
z = spins(spins) # Pragmatic way
z = spins.copy() # My favorite way
```

All of which are equally valid. Because this is a new item, changing it does not affect the original.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to create a new list is to use a list comprehension

```
def flip(spins, j):
    return [e * -1 if i == j else e for i, e in enumerate(spins)]
```

Multiply by `-1` can also just be `-e` so

```
def flip(spins, j):
    return [-e if i == j else e for i, e in enumerate(spins)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python treats mutable (list, dictionary, pandas dataframe and series) and immutable (int, tuple, float) data types differently as they get processed inside a function.

Immutable data type gets changed even if it's used inside a function. To avoid this, always make sure to do the processing on the copy of the data by calling `.copy()` method which creates a copy of the data in a new location.

`.copy()` works with all the above mentioned mutable data types.

This code will do the job for you:

```
def flip(spins,j):
    z = spins.copy()
    z[j] = z[j]*-1
    return z
```